# Update de feriados em tabela de SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-update

Possuo uma tabela SQL Server chamada DM_Tempo. Os campos dela são:

```
DtRef
AnoRef
MesRef
DiaRef
MesExtenso
CodDiaSemana
SemanaNumero
IndFeriado
```

E já possuem nela dias marcados como feriados (no caso, IndFeriado = 'SIM'). Mas o que eu estava querendo fazer era o seguinte, por exemplo: se uma data que foi numa sexta-feira (CodDiaSemana = 6) não é feriado, mas o dia anterior era, eu tenho que fazer um UPDATE pra essa sexta-feira ser considerada feriado também (tipo um feriadão). Tentei algo mais ou menos assim:

```
UPDATE DM_Tempo
SET IndFeriado = 'SIM'
WHERE AnoRef IN (2017,2018)
AND IndFeriado = 'NÃO'
AND CodDiaSemana = 6
AND IndFeriado IN (
SELECT IndFeriado FROM DM_TempoEmpresa T2 WHERE T2.DtRef = 
DATEADD(DAY,-1,T1.DtRef) AND T2.IndFeriado = 'SIM'
)
order by 2,1
```

Mas não funcionou. O que daria pra fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deverá resolver seu problema:

```
UPDATE tabela_tempo SET IndFeriado = 'SIM'
FROM DM_Tempo as tabela_tempo
WHERE tabela_tempo.AnoRef IN (2017, 2018)
  AND tabela_tempo.IndFeriado = 'NÃO'
  AND tabela_tempo.CodDiaSemana = 6
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM DM_TempoEmpresa T2 
                WHERE T2.DtRef = DATEADD(DAY, -1, tabela_tempo.DtRef)
                  AND T2.IndFeriado = 'SIM')
order by 2,1
```

Você não havia *"mapeado"* a tabela de fora (que será atualizada) - na verdade você se referia a ela como `T1` mas sem adicionar alias no *update*)